# ¿Como unificar dos tablas en una sola?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un reporte el cual debe mostrar la información de un item, así como sus localizaciones los diferentes almacenes y su stock actual. Uso SQL server con un openquery para obtener información de BaaN.

Lo que quiero realizar es algo parecido a la imagen que estoy adjuntando:

[image: Información]

Como se pueden dar cuenta, las marcas azules son una especie de encabezado que agrupa el número de ítem y la cantidad estimada que se requiere de ese item. Debajo de ese registro, se muestra la información sobre las diferentes localidades y stock de ese mismo item.

El problema que tengo, y que en realidad no sé cómo lograr, es que la información que obtengo desde SQL se muestre en ese formato para yo nada más jalarlo a mi aplicación.

El query actual que tengo, y que no muestra la parte azul es el siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
(am3p1, 'SELECT o.T$PDNO, REPLACE(o.T$SITM,'' '','''')T$SITM, o.T$CWAR, o.T$QUNE, o.T$CPES$1, w.T$LOCA, w.T$STKS FROM baan.tticst001305 o
INNER JOIN baan.twhinr140305 w ON REPLACE(o.T$SITM,'' '','''') = REPLACE(w.T$ITEM,'' '','''')
 WHERE o.T$PDNO = ''2GE000632'' AND w.T$LOCA <> '' '' ORDER BY o.T$SITM, w.T$IDAT')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según veo en los datos, el ordenamiento esta dado por la columna "item". Así que podrías hacer 2 queries separadas y usar **UNION**, luego ordenarlas por "Item" y un campo adicional que llamaremos "origen" para que luego de ordenarlo quede primero la cabecera.

No pondré nombres reales de campos, sino el concepto, ten en cuenta que ambas consultas deben retornar la misma cantidad de columnas y del mismo tipo.

Que sea OPENQUERY o no, no importa.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  /* hacemos el primer select, este ya lo tienes */
  (SELECT 1 as origen, miItem as item, las, demas, columnas, aqui 
       FROM tabla1 WHERE ...)
  UNION /* esto une las consultas en un solo resultado */
  /* este select lo armas como sea que necesites para calcular esos valores de cabecera */
  (SELECT 0 as origen, suItem as item, las, demas, columnas, aqui
       FROM tabla2 WHERE ...)
)
ORDER BY item, origen;
```

Así, primero unes los resultados, luego los ordenas por Item, y finalmente por origen, quedando primero el de menor origen.

Ahora, para que esto funcione, como las dos tablas tienen diferentes columnas, deberás usar un relleno para que las columnas queden igualadas.

Te explico como...

Supone que la tabla A tiene las columnas "nombre" y "dirección", y la tabla B tiene las columnas "cartas enviadas"..

La consulta sobre la tabla A deberá rellenar la columna "cartas enviadas" y la tabla B deberá rellenar las columnas de la tabla A..

```
(SELECT A.nombre, A.direccion, '' as cartarenviadas FROM A)
UNION
(SELECT '' as nombre, '' as direccion, B.cartasenviadas FROM B)
```

Espero que se halla entendido, cualquier cosa consultarme.

#### Nota:

A instancias de @rsciriano, utilizando `UNION ALL` en lugar de `UNION` obtendrás mayor performance ya que SQL no realiza el paso de eliminar duplicados.

Comment: Hola @rnd, si no se requiere eliminar los duplicados sería más óptimo usar [UNION ALL](http://www.mug-it.org.ar/343013-Impacto-en-la-performance-de-Union-vs-Union-ALL.note.aspx)

Comment: @rsciriano es cierto, pero las tablas tienen columnas diferentes, no veo que pueda haber duplicados.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que al usar `UNION`, SQL Server intentará buscar y eliminar los duplicados por lo que hará la consulta mas lenta. Cosa que no ocurrirá con `UNION ALL`

Comment: @rsciriano buen punto, no lo tenia tan claro. gracias por la info.

Comment: Hola @rnd. Muchas gracias por la clarificación, fue de bastante ayuda. Pude realizar la obtención de los datos y jugando también con mi grid logré el objectico. Me ayudó bastante su aportación.